# Unable to apply filter for json object in angular js with ng-option

Tags: angularjs

I have this json subtopics:

```
[{
    "id": "200",
    "topicID": "20",
    "name": "Support for project hosted by ncegitref1"

},
{
    "id": "201",
    "topicID": "20",
    "name": "Support for project hosted by rndwww (Stash)"
},
{
    "id": "210",
    "topicID": "120",
    "name": "Upload SSH key"
}]
```

and my javascript goes like this:

```
$http.get(urlsub).success(function(response) {
        $scope.subtopics = response;
        console.log($scope.subtopics);
    });

$scope.selectedTopic = {};
$scope.TopicChanged = function(topic) {
    $scope.displayTopicDescription = true;
    $scope.topicDesc = topic.description;
    $scope.selectedTopic.topicID = topic.id;
    $scope.sub = topic.id ;
    console.log($scope.sub);
};
```

My console prints the value 20. The subtopics stores the above json. I used filter in my ng-options as below,

```
<select id="selectSubtopic" ng-model="topicsPopulate" ng-disabled="!topicsPopulate" ng-options="subtopic.name for subtopic in subtopics | filter:{topicID:sub}:true ">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Subtopic</option>
</select>
```

upon using this filter, i see all the three subtopic.name in the dropdown instead of first two. I basically want to filter the subtopics based on the topicID that i send with $scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because AngularJS not seek equal values ​, the filter searches CONTAINS that value (20) and all your objects in json CONTAINS 20 topicId, but you can create a custom filter like:

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ControllerFirst',function($scope){
 $scope.subtopics = [{
    "id": "200",
    "topicID": 20,
    "name": "Support for project hosted by ncegitref1"

},
{
    "id": "201",
    "topicID": 20,
    "name": "Support for project hosted by rndwww (Stash)"
},
{
    "id": "210",
    "topicID": 120,
    "name": "Upload SSH key"
}];
$scope.sub= 20;
$scope.selectedTopic = {};
$scope.customFilter = function(topicID) {
    return function(subtopic) {
        return subtopic.topicID == topicID;
    }
}
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerFirst">
<select id="selectSubtopic" ng-model="topicsPopulate"  ng-options="subtopic.name for subtopic in subtopics | filter:customFilter(sub)">

    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Subtopic</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And here my fiddle with this example: https://jsfiddle.net/javierif/rk04nL90/

hope this help u ;D

Answer (score 0):

Here's a  working [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/YQaiad7CqIDgwzqdJO2x?p=info) of a solution.  I had to make a few assumptions related to topics since your code snippet didn't show how they were defined or initialized.

The primary change to your code was to the filter.  Instead of filtering based on a scope variable ($scope.sub) set in TopicChanged() I changed it to filter based on the ng-model associated with what I assumed is a select for topics.

So now your markup would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="selectedTopic" ng-options="topic.description for topic in topics" ng-change="TopicChanged()">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select a Topic</option>
</select>

<select id="selectSubtopic" ng-model="topicsPopulate" ng-disabled="!selectedTopic" ng-options="subtopic.name for subtopic in subtopics | filter: {topicID: selectedTopic.id} :true ">
  <option value="">Select Subtopic</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, this does'nt work. It displays "Upload SSH key" also in the dropdown.

Comment: Are you saying that the plunk doesn't work or its not the behavior what you were looking for?

Comment: Let me give you a clear picture. I have a two dropdowns, topic dropdown and subtopic dropdown. The subtopic dropdown remains disabled untill a topic is selected and i sent the selected topic as parameter in ng-change function which sets a $scope variable which i use in the subtopic dropdown to filter the subtopics belonging to this topic. But apparently, filter checks if the string is present, meaning to say that it selects id=2000 for id=20.

Comment: @KiranKumar - ok, I updated my answer and plunk to use the ng-disabled directive to handle the behavior you outlined.  As far as having an additional $scope variable that gets set in the change event, it isn't necessary since the ng-model of the topics select is updated and available for the filtering of the subTopics